# Problem with TTL autofocus on Canon 450d - is there a way to adjust?

Tags: autofocus, canon-450d, focus-adjust, back-focus

I have Canon EOS 450D, and it seems, that camera have problem with autofocusing, when i'm looking through optical viewfinder. If I switch camera to liveview - autofocus works correctly, but slow.
The problem popped, when i bought canon 50mm F1.8 II lens - it focuses terribly, even on inf. - looks like it's front-focused. Sometime ago i've heared, that there's adjustment screw, behind the mirror, and it's possible to adjust it, but i'm not sure - will it help, or i'll broke something.

And yes, there are no service centers near me, so i can't give camera to professionals.

Any advices? May be there's a way to adjust autofocus via some software?

Comment: the problem is fixed by service center. they performed adjustments of AF-matrix, so, now it looks like it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to take it to a service center for calibration. If you do it yourself you run the risk of totally mis aligning it. It could also be a lens issue since you say that it only happens with that lens.

Comment: i'm having front-focus even on my 28-105 3.5-4.5 lens, but it's so soft, that I can't figure out - where's the problem.. I'll try to check lens with other camera, it problem persists - i'll simply replace the lens.